# Is a T-SQL conditional TOP clause possible?

Tags: t-sql

I want to dynamically use TOP or not sort of like this...

```
SELECT @SomeNumber CASE WHERE 0 THEN TOP 5 COLUMNNAME
                        ELSE COLUMNNAME
                   END
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just used something like this:-

```
Declare @SQL nvarchar(max), @Params nvarchar(max)
set @Params = N''
Set @SQL = N'SELECT ' + Cast(@SomeNumber as varchar) + ' CASE WHERE 0 THEN TOP 5 COLUMNNAME
                        ELSE COLUMNNAME
                   END
FROM TABLE'

exec sp_executesql @SQL, @Params
```

Answer (score 21):

I hope to have understood your problem: you want to select the TOP 5 rows if you pass @SomeNumber = 0 else select all th etable rows

As a first straight implementation you can do something like that

```
declare @SomeNumber as int

set @SomeNumber = 5
-- set @SomeNumber = 1

SELECT TOP (SELECT @SomeNumber) COLUMNNAME FROM MYTABLE
```

you can change the parameter value in order to have how many rows you want

---

Otherwise i suggest you to implement a stored procedure (and maybe you already did that, otherwise you can follow the next steps in order to do it)

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[TOPCLAUSE]

    -- clause parameter
    @SomeNumber as integer

AS

IF @SomeNumber = 0 
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 5 COLUMNNAME FROM MYTABLE
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT COLUMNNAME FROM MYTABLE
END

GO
```

Then you can call

```
exec [dbo].[TOPCLAUSE] 0

exec [dbo].[TOPCLAUSE] 1
```

I probably not answered your question but let me know if it helped you

Comment: SELECT TOP (SELECT @SomeNumber) is perfect.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can.

You could either use dynamic SQL:

```
Declare @int int

set @int = 10

exec ('Select top '  + @int + ' * From Customers')
```

Or you could set `rowcount`

```
if (@someNumber != 0)
begin
set rowcount 5
end

select * From Customers

set rowcount 0
```

Comment: This was helpful, and I modified a stored proc to be dynamic by saying `IF @maxRows > 0 BEGIN SET ROWCOUNT @maxRows END`, querying, then setting ROWCOUNT back to 0 immediately after the query.

Answer (score 2):

Another loophole: make use of subquery's with row_number function

```
DECLARE @DoTopJN AS bit

SET @DoTopJN = 0 -- or 1

SELECT X.Sequence
       X.COLUMNA
       --etc

FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Y.Code) AS Sequence
             ,Y.COLUMNA
             ,Y.COLUMNB
             -- etc.
      FROM   Y) X

WHERE ((@DoTopJN = 0) OR (X.Sequence = 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, not the way you have it.

You can however use [`IF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) to test and run a different query:

```
IF (@SomeNumber = 0)
BEGIN
   SELECT TOP 5 ColumnName FROM Table
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SELECT ColumnName FROM Table
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options: conditional SQL or dynamic SQL.

(1) Conditional:

```
IF @SomeNumber = 0
    SELECT TOP 5 COLUMNAME FROM TABLE
ELSE
    SELECT COLUMNAME FROM TABLE
```

(2) Dynamic:  build up the query in a varchar() and pass it to sp_execute

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible because `TOP` is applied on not just a column but the whole row. You would have to create two different select statements and put them in a `IF ELSE` construct.

Comment: While the statement regarding top applying to a whole row not a column is correct, this can be achieved! see SPE109's answer!

Answer (score 0):

To correct SPE109's code:

```
DECLARE @SomeNumber INT = 0
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max), @Params nvarchar(max)
set @Params = N''
SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT ' + CASE WHEN @SomeNumber = 0 THEN '' ELSE 'TOP ' + CAST(@SomeNumber as varchar) END + ' COLUMNNAME FROM TABLE'
exec sp_executesql @SQL, @Params
```

Comment: You should either comment below their answer or ask a new question with what is not working with their solution for you (since that was already marked as the answer)

Comment: I cannot comment below their answer because it requires me to have 50 reputation points unfortunately. However, I tested the "Accepted Answer" and it produces invalid SQL code (Syntax Error).

Comment: The accepted answer produces this code:

`SELECT 5 CASE WHERE 0 THEN TOP 5 COLUMNNAME
                        ELSE COLUMNNAME
                   END
FROM TABLE`

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.